# what's the best way to subtract each element from the next element

Tags: python-3.x

I have very long accumulated list, and i want to subtract each element from the next element. So what's the best way? "The best in terms of readability and speed "

Ex: the list is:

```
res = [0, 1, 4, 6, 7]
```

And the result should be : `output=[1, 3, 2, 1]`
To clarify, the last element of the output came from `output[-1]= res[-1] - res[-2]`

So I've tried `[x-y for x, y in zip (res[::-1], res[::-1][1:])][::-1]`

It's so fast, but it's complicated and not readable "I think i will not remember what i did in the next couple of weeks"

P.S I am reversing the list using `res[::-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to reverse; just zip the list up into pairs:

```
>>> [i - j for i, j in zip(res[1:], res[:-1])]
[1, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: yes, you are right.
I think we can use `[i - j for i, j in zip(res[1:], res)]` without slicing res twice.